# ggsurvplot and ggplot lattice ?! Plotting kaplan-meier curve with cumulative incidence function

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survminer

I would like to plot a kaplan meier curve (KM) and cumulative events or cumulative incidence function (CIF) in one plot as a lattice.

I have switched recently from SAS to R, and in SAS you can do it all in one step using a macro (See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkiQP.png)), but I couldn't find something similar in R yet.

[image]

Currently, I run a code for two separate graphs. The first plots `survfit` object using `ggsurvplot` which results in a KM curve, While the second plots a `cuminc` object after a number of transformations using `ggplot`. `ggcompetingrisks` was not very optimizable, so I don't use it. Also I am interested in plotting one certain competing risk for example death from cancer, and not all competing risks.

Here is an example of my current code using the BMT data-frame from the `survminer` package.

```
library(survminer)
library(cmprsk)
data(BMT)

# I'll add the variable Death to plot overall survival.
BMT <- mutate(BMT, death = ifelse (status == 1, 1, 0))

# KM plot:
figKM <- ggsurvplot(survfit(Surv(ftime, death) ~ dis, BMT))
figKM

# CIF plot:
cif <- cuminc(ftime = BMT$ftime, fstatus = BMT$status, group = BMT$dis, cencode = 0)
cifDT <- cif %>% 
  list_modify("Tests" = NULL) %>% 
  map_df(`[`, c("time", "est"), .id = "id")  %>% 
  filter(id %in% c("0 1","1 1")) # to keep the incident I want

figCIF <- ggplot (cifDT, aes(x = time, y = est, color = id)) + geom_step(lwd = 1.2)
figCIF
```

is there a way to put figKM and figCIF together in a lattice plot? May by plotting them differently?

Comment: You may be looking for the cowplot package.

Comment: It did not work. It results with an empty figure.

Comment: Hard to know what to make of that comment. I get 'could not find function "map_df"' when I run your code.

Comment: @IRTFM Ok, are you able to combine two KM figures using the cowplot package? When I do, I get only an empty figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the contents of your figKM object with `class` and `str` you see that the first item in that list is a "plot", so this seems to do what you asked for in your comment:

```
 library(cowplot)
 plot_grid(figKM[[1]], figKM[[1]], nrow = 2)
```

[image]

I'm not a tidyverse-user so the `map_df` is perhaps some clone of the base function `Reduce` or `Map` but I don't have enough experience to a) know which package to load, or b) have the ability to figure out what is being done with your piped expressions. Commented code might have been more understandable. I am quite experienced with the `survival` package.